# Replacing Text Fields with ComboBox Type Fields on Create Page

Tags: asp.net-core, drop-down-menu, combobox, razor-pages

Good morning mega-minds! I've got a project I'm doing in ASP.Net Core using SQL Server database tables for the data. It has the basic EF built CRUD pages, and I've got everything working as it should. But what I would like to do is have selection fields (like ComboBoxes) on my Create and Edit pages. These fields would be linked to a different table in the same database that would have data a user could select. Below is an image of my Create page so far.

[image: Creation Page]

And here is the code for my model...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EpicorSolutionInfo.Models
{
    public class SolutionsData
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public int SprintID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select the type of component.")]
        [Display(Name = "Component Type")]
        public string CompType { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the name of the component.")]
        [Display(Name = "Component Name")]
        public string CompName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Business Object/Table Name")]
        public string BizObjTblName { get; set; }

        public string Notes { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the Issue name this is for.")]
        [Display(Name = "Issue")]
        public string IssueNum { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "In Solution")]
        public bool InSolution { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Prod Confirmation")]
        public bool ProdConfirm { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Prod Confirm By")]
        public string ProdConfirmBy { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Prod Confirm Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime ProdConfirmDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've done some searching, but haven't found a simple solution for accomplishing what I'm wanting. I'm sure there's got to be a simple way to turn a field into a ComboBox and link it to another DB table. Any ideas or links that could point me in the right direction would be appreciated. Thank you for your time and have a great day!

Comment: Hi @Shawn Leenerts ,I think no need turn a field to combobox. You need store the database data in ViewBag and set it as source to combobox. Besides the combobox owns the name `CompType `. Then the model binding system will bind the model property by the name.